# SQL Server : how can I descend using an order top

Tags: sql

I am trying to order the last 5 entries to the database and select them to show but I am having no luck, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8bd8a/2 as you can see I replicated the code I have and you can see it is ordering by [id] how can I change the SQL code so that the 9 in the ID column starts at the bottom instead of at the top.. so that it can be like

- 5
- 6
- 7
- 8
- 9

Comment: Just use `order by id` or `order by id asc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to wrap your original statement in an outer statement that sorts ascending:

```
select * from (
  select top 5 *
  from yourtable
  order by id desc
) a 
order by id asc
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8bd8a/13)

Or you could use a common table expression (cte):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT TOP (5) * 
  FROM YourTable ORDER BY id DESC 
)

SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

The following query should provide you the expected result:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT TOP 5 T2.*
      FROM yourtable T2
      ORDER BY T2.id DESC) T
ORDER BY T.id
```

Hope this will help you.